# BIGQUERY - LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to find 5th highest salary in bigquery using this query but it gives me error

`LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.`

I believe this is the right query for sql for this question but something is not working out in bigquery. Can anybody help me with this? :)

```
select  concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as Name, salary
from `table` w1
where 4 = (select count(distinct(salary))
 from  `table` w2
 where w2.salary > w1.salary)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query appears to be returning rows that have four larger salaries.  That would be the fifth largest salary.  So, just use `dense_rank()`:

```
select w.*
from (select w.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from `table` w
     ) w
where seqnum = 5;
```

Comment: Hi, @Gordon thank you for the answer. Your answer is of course correct and works well. But if we can change something in my previous query then what would that be if you can tell me? Thank you.

Comment: @Jazz . . . Very hard to do.  Better to use window functions.  Unfortunately working around this problem in BigQuery can be challenging.

Comment: Get it! Thanks Gordon. But my query should work in mysql, right?

Comment: @Jazz . . . Yes.  And happily MySQL now supports `dense_rank()` which is the better solution in both databases.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Using functions like DENSE_RANK(), ROW_NUMBER() and such for big volumes of data usually ends up with some thing like Resource Limits Exceeded error.

Depends on your real use case - you can consider below alternatives:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
```

OR

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 5)[SAFE_OFFSET(4)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

Both above versions should give you a record with 5th highest salary

Comment: I think these queries might fail to give the right answer when there is same salary for two different people. As in same salary should be ranked same followed by contiguous sequence of ranks . ex: 1,2,3...

Comment: Yes. note in answer: "Depends on your real use case - you can consider below alternatives:"

Comment: Yes true! But thanks for another angle of it. The use of `offset` is something very new to me so thanks for introducing it in here. Much appreciate @Mikhail

Comment: sure. no problem :o)